# windows 8 split app customization

Tags: javascript, html

as we know windows 8 split app show tiles so there i want to show images and on each tile every image should be different.

here is what i am doing on default.html page where  tag is

```
<div class="item">
<img alt="some text" data-win-bind="source: imagePath">
<div class="item-overlay">
                <h4 class="item-title" data-win-bind="textContent: title"></h4>
                <h6 class="item-subtitle win-type-ellipsis" data-win-bind="textContent: subtitle"></h6>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

and here is the code of data.js file

```
var sampleGroups = [
            { key: "group1", title: "Group Title: 1", subtitle: "Group Subtitle: 1", **imagePath:"path of image file 1",** backgroundImage: darkGray, description: groupDescription },
            { key: "group2", title: "Group Title: 2", subtitle: "Group Subtitle: 2", **imagePath:"path of image file 2",** backgroundImage: lightGray, description: groupDescription },
            { key: "group3", title: "Group Title: 3", subtitle: "Group Subtitle: 3",**imagePath:"path of image file 3",** backgroundImage: mediumGray, description: groupDescription },
            { key: "group4", title: "Group Title: 4", subtitle: "Group Subtitle: 4",imagePath:"path of image file 4", backgroundImage: lightGray, description: groupDescription },
            { key: "group5", title: "Group Title: 5", subtitle: "Group Subtitle: 5", imagePath:"path of image file 5", backgroundImage: mediumGray, description: groupDescription },
            { key: "group6", title: "Group Title: 6", subtitle: "Group Subtitle: 6", **imagePath:"path of image file 6",** backgroundImage: darkGray, description: groupDescription }
        ];
```

Comment: I haven't followed Windows 8 implementation details, so if this is a stupid question I can only apologise, but that said: are those asterisks present in the code, or are they to highlight something in the question? And, also, where are you stuck; what help do you need?

Comment: asterisks represents my code, i am unable to show the images on the default page. also i have tried <img alt="some text" data-win-bind="src: imagePath"> this also not works for me :(

Answer (score 0):

here is the solution (thanks to Mr. Usman ur Rehman)

open data.js and change the code according to the given below code

> function generateSampleData() {
>           var itemContent = "
>
> Curabitur class aliquam vestibulum nam curae maecenas sed...";

```
    // These three strings encode placeholder images. You will want to set the
    // backgroundImage property in your real data to be URLs to images.
    var darkGray =  "images/1.png";
    var lightGray = "images/1.png";
    var mediumGray = "images/1.png";

    // Each of these sample groups must have a unique key to be displayed
    // separately.
    var sampleGroups = [
        { key: "group1", title: "Group Title: 1", subtitle: "Group Subtitle: 1", backgroundImage: darkGray, description: groupDescription },
        { key: "group2", title: "Group Title: 2", subtitle: "Group Subtitle: 2", backgroundImage: lightGray, description: groupDescription },
        { key: "group3", title: "Group Title: 3", subtitle: "Group Subtitle: 3", backgroundImage: mediumGray, description: groupDescription }, .....
```